# How to get the PHP include function to work with proxy settings?

Tags: php, proxy, include, proxy-server

```
<?php
$incfile = $_REQUEST["file"];
include($incfile);
?>
```

upload.php file:

```
<?php
$context = array(
    'http' => array(
        'proxy' => "tcp://proxy.example.com:80",
        'request_fulluri' => true,
        'verify_peer'      => false,
        'verify_peer_name' => false,
    )
);
stream_context_set_default($context);
?>
```

proxy.php file:

```
auto_prepend_file=proxy.php
allow_url_include=1
```

php.ini:

I browse to http://testexample.com/upload.php?file=http://example.com/file.php but http://example.com/file.php times out with error Warning: include(): failed to open stream: Connection timed out. I played with echo file_get_contents and used the URL path and that works fine as it appears to honor the proxy settings. So does anyone know what the issue might be with using include or why it does not use my proxy settings?

Edit: As a workaround I used this code below:

```
<?php
$incfile = $_REQUEST["file"];
$filecontent = file_get_contents($incfile);
eval($filecontent);
?>
```

The problem with this though is that it reads in the PHP as a string and not the whole file. So I have to remove the PHP beginning and ending tags which changes the GET request body so effects my results. So even though it kinds works, the include function is really what I need.

Comment: Are you sure you want to using `include()` with a remote file? When you request a PHP file from a server, it normally executes the script, it doesn't return the source code. But `include()` needs the code.

Comment: You're trying to include PHP code from a remote file passed by a request argument? This is an _enormous_ security hole.

Comment: Yes that is the point. I am testing remote code execution for security vulnerabilities and this is a dev environment and would never be used for production. @Barmar yes i need it to execute the remote file code. In a test I was able to pass http://127.0.0.1/file.php that has hosted up locally and it worked as desired. It is when I try to access a remote file hosted that I have to use a proxy where it does not use the proxy settings.

Comment: If you just need to execute the code on the remote server, use `file_get_contents`, not `include`.

Comment: Yeah that is my work around but that reads it in as a string instead of just running the whole file. I have to remove the php header and closing tags to make it work. I would rather not do that.

Comment: But ultimately my question is there a way to get the `include` function to honor my proxy settings like `file_get_contents` does?

Comment: @Chris What is crazy is that I have seen a number of people ask this very question and so far none of them have an answer. I wonder is this not possible in PHP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you need your http requests for example.com to go to go through proxy.example.com. Would it suffice to simply override DNS for example.com to point to proxy.example.com - perhaps in the hosts file - on this development server? Then you could

```
include 'http://example.com/file.php';
```

If you want to limit the solution to PHP, you could define a custom stream wrapper for your proxy.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.stream-wrapper-register.php

http://php.net/manual/en/stream.streamwrapper.example-1.php

Comment: Thank you so much! The hosts file was the answer and now I don't have to mess with proxy settings at all!